# Calling function from another controller bug

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 controllers: UsersController and AnalyticsController.

When I run:

```
//UsersController:
function dummyFunction(){
    $this->Analytic->_loadChartFromId($chart_id);
}
```

the output is:

```
Query: _loadChartFromId
```

Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_loadChartFromId' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]

The `_loadChartFromId()` function takes $chart_id as an argument and returns an array as output. I have no idea why `Query: _loadChartFromId` appears.

Comment: Where is the `_loadChartFromId()` method defined?

Comment: @Nick AnalyticsController I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call other controller methods from your controller.

In your users controller, `$this->Analytic` is an instance of the Analytic model, not the AnalyticsController.  So CakePHP thinks you are trying to call a public method called `_loadChartFromId()` on the Analytic model, which, as you know, doesn't exist.

The reason you get the error is because if you try to call a non-existent method of a model, CakePHP tries to convert it to one of its [Magic Find Types](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types). Of course, it's not a valid Magic Find Type either, so you get a SQL error.

**Solution**

It's difficult to provide a complete solution as we only have part of your code, but you are perhaps violating the concept of MVC with the way you're coding your app.

You need to do one of two things:

1. Move `_loadChartFromId()` to your users controller.  This seems to me like it would be counter-intuitive, as it probably has nothing to do with the User.
2. Move the method to your Analytic model.  You would need to make it public so the controller can access it, and in your users controller you would need to make sure you have the Analytic model loaded.

   ```
   class Analytic extends AppModel {

       public function _loadChartFromId($chart_id) {
          // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Then you can call the method as you were doing before, from your users controller.

Answer (score 0):

I could have opted to close this question as an exact duplicate of at least 5 other questions (if you search for "cakephp another controller").
But the answers there are just terrible. They actually try to invoke new Dispatchers or requestAction().

So **if** your question is about another controller method:

The short answer is: You don't.

The long answer: You still dont. That's a typical beginners mistake.
You should put the functionality into a component if it is mainly business logic. The component then can be accessed from multiple controllers.

If it is more like model data (as in your example), put the functionality into the model layer (in an appropriate model). this way you can also access it from anywhere in your application.

Also: Accessing protected methods from other objects is never a good idea. Use public methods if you intend to use it from "outside" the object.

**If** your question is about a model method:
You need to include your model in your controller before you can use it.
Either by using `public $uses` or by using `loadModel('ModelName')` or even `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName')`.